# Using "float: left" in a menu's "a" tag

Tags: css, css-float

Including the "float: left" at the place labeled "here!!!" made the padding of the "a" element independent of the padding of the ancestor "ul" element. Also the space between the "a" elements disappeared, as shown in picture A (before including "float: left") and picture B (after).

[image]

[image]

Could someone explain why this happens for me?

```
#top-menu {
    width: 470px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    border: solid;
}

#top-menu ul {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: solid;
}

#top-menu li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#top-menu li a {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    color: #5A6770;
    float: left; /* <----- HERE!!! -----*/
    padding: 15px 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#top-menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #ECEFF2;
    border-color: #D1D6D9;
}

#top-menu li a:active {
    background-color: #E4E7EB;
    border-color: #BAC1C6;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) inset;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting your markup for `#top-menu` and its children?

Comment: `/* <----- HERE!!! -----*/` Can't really miss it.

Comment: Do you really need `float:left;`? Isn't `display:inline-block` sufficient?

Comment: Zeta The only common is that they make elements to show in one line. Everything else in their behavior is completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `<a>` element is **inline** element. And when you add it `float:left` it starts acting like **block** element.

You can only have margin and padding on inline elements which affects only the "line" .. i.e left and right. But you can't top and bottom because for example. Imagine that you have long paragraph, about 10 lines. And somewhere you have span or a - inline elements. There is no logic to give them top and bottom margin and padding, cause the all paragraph will brake, but you can add left and right.

Very good explanation you can find [HERE](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/).

Comment: You don't know how mad I was getting at a couple of responsive `<a>` which had floats on desktop and needed to be centered in mobile.Thanks for the explanation, I overrun their behavior in mobile with `display: block; float: none` and I finally got them where I wanted.